# Have a JS function *constantly* listen for clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, click

This seems like something that should be really simple. I have a few images animating on a page, but I want the user to be able to click on any one of them *at any time* and then go to a related page.

Problem is, evidently clicks stopped being listened for at some point if I use a loop to search through an array of clickable items. I thought having a function separate from the one that handles the animation would allow it to constantly listen no matter what the animated images were doing, but it seems once the "complete" function is called (for the "animate" function), the function that is listening for clicks (wholly separate from the animation, and using setInterval to listen for clicks) stops listening.

Oddly enough, I believe I did not have this problem when just listening for "img" instead of an array of different images.

Ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? More info needed? *I tried to remove any irrelevant code below.*

```
var links = ["#portfolio", "#animations", "#games"];

$(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
        for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
            $(links[i]).click(function(){
                window.location.replace("http://www.gog.com");
            });
        }
    }, 500);
});

$(document).ready(function() {

    links.forEach(function(current){

        //various vars
        var link = $(current);
        var footer3 = $(".footer3");
        var over = true;
        var randomTime = 3000*(Math.random()+1);

        //dust vars
        ...

        //image vars
        var imageUrlShadow = 'images/home/non-char/shadow-pngs/shadow';
        var imageUrlCharacter = 'images/home/char-pngs/';
        var portfolioSrc;
        var animationsSrc;
        var gamesSrc;

        //animate the characters
        link.animate({
            top: '0'
        }, {
            duration: randomTime,
            easing: 'easeOutBounce',
            step: function(now, tween) {

                /*handle shadows*/
                ...

                /*handle characters*/
                if (now < -25 && over == false) {

                    ...

                } else if (now >= -25) {

                    ...
                }

                $("#"+ link.data("portfolio")).attr('src', portfolioSrc);
                $("#"+ link.data("animations")).attr('src', animationsSrc);
                $("#"+ link.data("games")).attr('src', gamesSrc);

                /*handle dust*/
                var dustDoneMoving = '-50px';
                var dustNotMoving = '0px';
                //if link is NOT touching footer3
                ...

            //set to "sitting" images when animation is done
            complete: function() {
                ...
                setTimeout(function() {
                    ...
                }, 1000);
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: Why do you need `setInterval` and loop in it???

Comment: `.click` attaches a permanent click listener to an element ("permanent" until it is removed, anyway). You're adding loads of permanent listeners at a rate of 2 per second; surely one permanent listener per image is sufficient?

Comment: yeah click handlers should not involve a timing element. is there something we're missing?

Comment: If you say your listeners stop listening then you should look into using the [on(events, selector, handler)](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function and attach an event to the body (or some parent element) that listens for clicks from elements that match the specified selector.

Comment: Nope, you're not missing anything; I just wasn't sure the best way to handle this. I thought setInterval might be one option to help the loop continue to listen.

Answer (score 0):

```
var links = ["#portfolio", "#animations", "#games"];

$(function() {
   $(links.join(',')).click(function(){
        window.location.replace("http://www.gog.com");
   });
});
```

One time only and listener will be attached to the image.

Answer (score 0):

Consider listening via `window`

```
var links = ["#portfolio", "#animations", "#games"];

$(window).on('click', links.join(', '), function() {
  // do what you wanna
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code. See, if this works now.

I have added one more array which contains some URLs. So, the intention is that on click of a particular element, its respective URL should be opened.
So, the sequence in these array will matter with respect to each other.

Also, I have made use of 'on', so that 'click' event should be handled even during animation.

```
var links = ["#portfolio", "#animations", "#games"];

var sites = ["http://www.gog.com", "http://www.gog1.com", "http://www.gog2.com"]; //change these to the expected URLs

$(function() {

   for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
      $(document ).on("click",links[i],function(){
                window.location.replace(sites[i]);
      });
   }

});
```

Comment: Thanks. My original question actually didn't involve this, but after finding a workaround for my earlier issue I am now working on this. Unfortunately, for some reason I keep getting "undefined" when using "pages[i]" for window.location.replace. (It works fine when specifying an index, like "pages[0]") : `var links = ["#portfolio", "#animations", "#games"];
var pages = ["http://www.gog.com", "http://www.google.com", "http://www.hamumu.com"]; $(function() {
  for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
   $(links[i]).click(function() {
    window.location.replace(pages[i]);
   });
  }
    });`

Answer (score 0):

**I apologize, it turns out that, apparently, the problem was related to the z-index.** There were some other divs with 0 opacity "covering up" the array divs.
Setting the z-index to 2 for the array items has fixed the matter. Again, my apologies.